# Fetching HTML into a <div> and overwrite content

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with a top panel and a body part. The top panel can be toggled between hidden and shown.
The body part should contain the actual content of the website.

As I don't want to hard-code every single site, I would like to stay with the panel and only reload the content.

This seems to can be done using AHAH and [this](http://www.xfront.com/microformats/AHAH.html) tutorial.

The problem is that, if new content is loaded, it just pushes the old content down.
My question is, how can I overwrite the old content with the new, fetched content?

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: thanks a lot to everyone of you, i will have a look!
I have already been using javascript and innerHTML i was just thinking there would be a better way to do this. So i will stick with this.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
document.getElementById('yourDivID').innerHTML = theHTML;
```

However any JavaScript in `theHTML` will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The prototype.js library has a good function, Ajax.Updater(), to do this sort of thing, and it is less limited than the ahah.js lib, it sounds (can harvest a chunk of any page, local or remote, unlike AHAH).  Like jquery, there is a special $() function to get at stuff, use that to prune before appending.

```
$( 'target_div_id').childElements().each( function( child) { child.remove(); } )
Ajax.Updater( 'target_div_id', 'related_page.html')
```

Trailing options can be added to refine how much of the downloaded "page" is used.

[Ajax.Updater](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater)
[Element](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery:

```
$("#divid").html("some html value goes here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery would be the best way, here is a link to that page;

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val